# Mongodb aggregation framework alternative for Cassandra

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, cassandra, apache-spark

Because of external reasons we thinking to switch from MongoDB to Cassandra. Cassandra is scale good, write fast, read good. But there we really stuck is queries features. We using MongoDB queries features activelly and we also use mongo's aggregation features very activelly. So could you please point me to alternatives technology, which could compensate monodb rich queries and aggragation framework? Could it be Hadoop or Spark?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apache Spark is most powerful cassandra complement. With Spark you can group, join, sort, filter, and whatever you imagine. There are some projects that built an abstraction layer in Spark over Cassandra and let you apply this operations.

Two commonly projects are:

- [Stratio Deep](https://github.com/Stratio/stratio-deep)
- [Datastax Connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector)